# Laravel - How can i set the Auth::attempt to a user if i only have a JWT token with the email and the id

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, cookies, jwt

I have two projects; the first is just a JWT login that redirects, if successful, to another Laravel project with the token. In the other project, Ivalidatede the token, but that project is already with a lot of code started, and it works with the methods `Auth::user()->"retrieve data"`.

The problem is that I don't know how to authenticate with the `Auth::attempt()`, with only the email or the JWT, or what is the best way to do it, if I can delete all the lines with the Auth:: and instance the cookies, get the payload and replace the `Auth::attempt()` with some model for the cookie user.

Thanks, and sorry if my attempt to explain the issue is unclear.
And if I'm doing something wrong, please let me know; I'm a beginner at this.

I don't know if the best way to do this is to try the `Auth::attempt` / `Auth::user` or quit that and replace it with the payload that has the JWT in the cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've correctly validated the user, you can login with `Auth::login($user)`

See the docs https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#authenticate-a-user-instance

Comment: Thanks man, now i know how to login even just the User's ID, really thanks